# Why is unicode written like U+0000?

Tags: unicode

I've always wondered why id unicode is writtent with a U then a plus(+) and then a number ?

I understand that the `U` is for Unicode and that the number is some kind of ID for the unicode but why is there a plus(+) sign in between ? Why not `U0000` instead of `U+0000` ?

Comment: Is your question about why historically this convention was chosen ?

Comment: I wonder if there is a signification for the `+` sign or if it is just historical like you said.